# Pattern Matching for instanceof throwing a confusing error: expression type Triple is a subtype of pattern type Triple

Tags: java, pattern-matching, instanceof, java-record

I have Java 19, and I am attempting to do some simple pattern-matching on a record that I created. However, Java is giving me a very confusing compilation error. Here is the simplest example I could make that causes the error.

```java
public class ExpressionTypeIsASubsetOfPatternType
{

   public record Triple(int a, int b, int c) {}

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      System.out.println("Java Version = " + System.getProperty("java.version"));

      final Triple input = new Triple(1, 2, 3);

      if (input instanceof Triple t)
      {

         System.out.println("Made it here");

      }

   }

}
```

And here is the error that it gives me when I try to run/compile.

```
$ java ExpressionTypeIsASubsetOfPatternType.java
ExpressionTypeIsASubsetOfPatternType.java:15: error: expression type Triple is a subtype of pattern type Triple
      if (input instanceof Triple t)
                ^
1 error
error: compilation failed
```

Surprisingly enough, googling this error showed up nothing useful. I am so used to punching in an error and immediately seeing the problem. I imagine that it is because this feature is so new.

Anyways, the closest thing I could find is a [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8260566) that is related, but definitely not the same issue that I am dealing with.

Finally, here is the relevant info about my java version.

```
$ java --version
openjdk 19 2022-09-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 19+36-2238)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19+36-2238, mixed mode, sharing)
```

```
$ javac --version
javac 19
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java is just being "nice": it recognizes that the test will *always* succeed (because `input` is known to be a `Triple`, which is already a subtype of the test type `Triple`), so it produces an error telling you that you're doing something useless (with a roundabout message).

This is the same idea that makes

```
void foo() {
  return;
  return; // error: unreachable statement
}
```

an error: there is a useless piece of code that might indicate (serious) programmer error, so the compiler forces you to rethink the code.

The relevant section of the JLS is [15.20.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2), which says

> > *InstanceofExpression*:
> >
> > - ...
> > - *RelationalExpression* `instanceof` *Pattern*
>
> ...
>
> The following rules apply when `instanceof` is the pattern match operator:
>
> - ...
> - If the type of the *RelationalExpression* is a subtype of the type of the *Pattern*, then a compile-time error occurs.

I.e. this is indeed an intended part of the language and not just a compiler bug or something.

Comment: That makes sense. Your answer actually led me to go look at the JLS, and I see the evidence backing up what you are saying. Could you edit your answer to include the following information? I will accept it then -- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3.1.5

Comment: Specifically, the part in bold on the JLS site is the exact answer to my question and the evidence for your answer

Comment: @davidalayachew Er, what? I was already checking the JLS myself when I made the new edit. Your comment has the wrong quote.

Comment: Right you are, I misread the JLS and thought it was saying something different entirely. My quote was actually talking about variable names, but I thought it was talking about the condition being guaranteed to evaluate to `true`. Either way, you found the right answer. I have accepted this.

Answer (score 5):

[HTNW's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74978688/3100123) is the correct response but I find this behavior by the compiler to be non-ideal as it doesn't account for null references. There's some inconsistency here:

```
String s = null;
if (s instanceof String) {}
```

```
String s = null;
if (s instanceof String string) {}
```

The first option will compile, the second one will give the the error "Pattern type 'String' is the same as expression type". This means that `instanceof` can be used as a null check but not if pattern matching is used. Makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I actually had a chance to talk to the folks making this feature, and they said that this is something being addressed too. Long story short, it's called something like an **Unconditional Pattern**, and that is something that they are still working on atm. It's a little confusing because I thought there would be a JEP for unconditional patterns, but I didn't see one. Either way, once this "Unconditional Pattern" is hammered out, then this should be dealt with too.

Comment: But the explanation isn't correct?
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2
It's not failing because the pattern always returns true (it doesn't per the link above because, null will cause the pattern to fail regardless of the type) but because a type is considered a subtype of itself. Or at least that's how I read it.