# JAVA 17 : Pattern matching subtype

Tags: java, eclipse, java-17

I'm using Java 17, the last line shouldnt compile, but when i'm using eclipse it does compile, now i'm confused should the value be a subtype or it can be anything?

```
Double value = 123.3;
if(value instanceof Double ) {}
if(value instanceof Double data) {} // DOES NOT COMPILE
```

Comment: Why should it not compile? Please share all the details.

Comment: i'm reading a book that says, it must be a subType only, when i test that on an IDE it does compile, i'm asking to make sure that's a book error

Comment: "i'm using eclipse" from what I remember Eclipse uses its own compiler. What you see is probably another difference between it and "official compiler".

Comment: Anyway based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/74978688 it looks like compilation error was expected, which suggests bug in Eclipse compiler.

Comment: Interesting. This does not compile for me either, using javac (not Eclipse).  But I cannot find anything in the Java Language Specification that says specifying the same type in an instanceof pattern should be an error.

Comment: @VGR Hello. Regarding "*But I cannot find anything in the Java Language Specification that says specifying the same type in an instanceof pattern should be an error*" how about fragment "If the type of the `RelationalExpression` is a subtype of the type of the `Pattern`, then a compile-time error occurs." from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2? IMO this can be applied here if we consider each reference type as subtype of itself (in other words Double can be considered as subtype of Double).

Comment: @Pshemo I did see that, but I have doubts about whether that was the intended meaning of “subtype.”

Comment: It's a bug in the eclipse compiler for java.

Comment: @VGR it seems, it was truly meant that way but JDK 21 is about to get rid of that rule.

Answer (score 7):

[JLS-15.20.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2) explicitly says that this is not allowed:

> If the type of the RelationalExpression is a subtype of the type of the Pattern, then a compile-time error occurs

Regarding the meaning of "subtype", [JLS-4.10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10) states:

> The *supertypes* of a type are obtained by reflexive and transitive closure over the direct supertype relation, written `S >1 T`, which is defined by rules given later in this section. We write `S :> T` to indicate that the supertype relation holds between S and T.
>
> S is a *proper supertype* of T, written `S > T`, if `S :> T` and `S ≠ T`.
>
> The *subtypes* of a type T are all types U such that T is a supertype of U, and the null type. We write `T <: S` to indicate that that the subtype relation holds between types T and S.
>
> T is a *proper subtype* of S, written `T < S`, if `T <: S` and `S ≠ T`.

From the wording it is clear that a type `T` must be a subtype (and supertype) of itself. If `T` cannot be a subtype (supertype) of itself it would be unnecessary to define the terms "proper subtype" and "proper supertype"

---

The reason for this decision is documented in [JEP-394](https://openjdk.org/jeps/394):

> Make it a compile-time error for a pattern instanceof expression to compare an expression of type S against a pattern of type T, where S is a subtype of T. (This instanceof expression will always succeed and is then pointless. The opposite case, where a pattern match will always fail, is already a compile-time error.)

---

Note that (as Holger has pointed out) the upcoming version Java 21 will drop the requirement that RelationalExpression must not be a subtype of the type of the Pattern. That means that with Java 21 your code will compile.

Comment: BTW the term  "reflexive" is *probably* meant to say that `T` is a supertype of itself (`T`)

Comment: Forbidding something just because it seems pointless, is a strange reasoning. Consistency with other uses of `instanceof` looks far more important to me.  It’s not even true that this test will always succeed, as it will fail if the runtime value is `null`. Further, it contradicts the way, pattern matching is supposed to evolve. Consequently, the current state of affairs is that JDK 21 will drop this rule.

Answer (score 6):

That syntax is part of a relatively new feature (JDK 16) in Java which they call *pattern matching* and is detailed in [JEP 394](https://openjdk.org/jeps/394).

The example is trivial if the runtime type of the variable equals its declared type. So let's pretend we instead had a

```
Object value;
```

whose runtime type happened to be `Double`.

```
if (value instanceof Double) {
  ...
}
```

The inside of this `if` statement will run if `value` is a `Double` at runtime. However, the *compile-time* type of that variable is still `Object`, which led to a very common (and redundant) paradigm.

```
if (value instanceof Double) {
  Double data = (Double)value; // This cast ALWAYS succeeds
  ...
}
```

Since, after checking the type, we probably want to use the variable as that type.

So with JEP 394, we can write

```
if (value instanceof Double data) {
  ...
}
```

which does the typecheck *and* the cast in one go. On top of that, the variable is bound *immediately*, and is available in later conjunctive clauses.

```
if ((value instanceof Double data) && (data.doubleValue() > 0.0)) {
  ...
}
```

This works since `data` is a `Double`, not an `Object`. As opposed to the more verbose pre-pattern-matching syntax

```
if ((value instanceof Double) && (((Double)value).doubleValue() > 0.0)) {
  ...
}
```

or

```
if (value instanceof Double) {
  Double data = (Double)value;
  if (data.doubleValue() > 0.0) {
    ...
  }
}
```

In your particular case, since both the declared and runtime type are `Double`, the extra variable doesn't do you any favors. It's a degenerate case where the pattern matching syntax isn't useful. But it's still allowed. Depending on compiler, you might get a warning about this.